# Custom interface object invisible after switching between tabs

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, calayer, nsview, nsbox

My app has a preferences window with a toolbar. Its preferences tab is a separate NSView object. When I put standard buttons, boxes, etc. in each view, switching between tabs work wonderfully, but when I add custom boxes or views, the custom objects become invisible after switching between tabs.

How do I fix this?

Notice that I use method `drawLayer:` in each custom object. I mark the "layer" checkbox in IB for the superview.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudn't use the implicit layer on a layer-backed view to do custom drawing. Although this sometimes works, it is not supported.

Instead, you should create your own `CALayer` object and add it to the view's implicit layer using `[self.layer addSublayer:yourCustomLayer]`. You would then set your object as the layer's delegate and implement `drawLayer:inContext:` to do your custom drawing.

Comment: This didn't work. I create new project, add NSTabView object and put standard button in first TabView and put my custom object in second TabView. I also change my custom object code as you say, but that haven't effect.